# Rails Could not find generator via command line in Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm brand new in Ruby. I'm following [this Ruby tutorial.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) Everything seems fine till 4.1, but in 4.2 when I run `ruby bin\rails generate controller welcome index` in cmd, it says **Could not find generator welcome.** 
Following are my windows setup details:

Ruby version: 2.1.5

Rails version: 4.1.8

Please forgive my silly mistakes if there are any.

Comment: As I mentioned I am using windows.

Comment: try changing `welcome` to `Welcome`. do you get the same error message?

Answer (score 0):

its for Linux

```
$ bin/rails generate controller welcome index
```

for windows try

```
$ rails generate controller welcome index
```

the later one also works for other OSes. or for more info try

```
rails g controller --help
```